# Script that delete value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#').change(function () {
    var php_var2 = "<?php echo $br; ?>";
    var php_var3 = "<?php echo $rb; ?>";
    if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING') {
        $("#txt36,#txt49").val('');
    } else if {
        //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
        $("#txt36").val(php_var2);
    } else {
        //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
        $("#txt49").val(php_var3);
    }
});
```

I have two textbox txt36, txt49 and select onchange event. When I choose NEGOTIATED or SHOPPING the value of txt36 and txt49 is equal to " " and if I choose RFQ the value of txt36 should be none, If choose BIDDING the value of txt49 should be none also. But this code didn't work.

Comment: `}else if{` needs a condition.  Otherwise, you want `}else {` - Also `$('#')` probably needs some sort of ID for your select element.

Comment: You selected by $("#"). Are you sure this will work?

Comment: What is it you think you're selecting with `$("#")`?

Answer (score 0):

> But this code didn't work.

You have used only `#`

```
$('#').change(function(){ // ... });
```

Where is the `id` ? it should be, something like

```
$('#selectId').change(function(){ // ... }); // <select id="selectId">
```

or

```
$('select').change(function(){ // ... }); // using the tag name
```

or

```
$('.selectClass').change(function(){ // ... }); // if it has a class, i.e. <select class="selectClass">
```

Also, `else if` needs a condition like `else if(condition)`. But, I think, you can use

```
if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING') {
    $("#txt36,#txt49").val('');
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'RFQ') {
    $("#txt36").val('');
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'BIDDING') {
    $("#txt49").val('');
}
else {
    //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
    $("#txt36").val(php_var2);
    $("#txt49").val(php_var3);
}
```

Comment: it works, but I want to do is if BIDDING selected the value of RFQ should be clear, or if RFQ selected the value of BIDDING should be clear too.

Answer (score 0):

I see two mistakes:

- initial selector is wrong: `$("#")`
- `else if` is missing a condition: `else if(...) {`

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var php_var2 = "<?php echo $br; ?>";
    var php_var3 = "<?php echo $rb; ?>";
    if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING') {
        $("#txt36,#txt49").val('');
    } else {
        //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
        $("#txt49").val(php_var3);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm a beginner in programing can you teach me how to do that?

Comment: I added a possible fix in my answer, but I don't understand the difference between your last 2 cases

Comment: I want to add else $("#txt36").val(php_var2); how to do this?

Comment: on which condition should this happen ?